# Docker Compose build with message path not found

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I try to add another container into my Docker environment. For the handling I'm using portainer and try to run an given compose file (With modifications, because the original one was not working at all)
What I did in steps:
First I did:

```
sudo git clone https://github.com/harmjan/fritzbox-metrics.git
```

To download the soruce. it will be placed in the folder `/opt/fritzbox-metrics` and I've checked, it is there!

Then I went into portainer to create a new stack with the following lines:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  fritzbox-metrics:
    build: /opt/fritzbox-metrics/Dockerfile
    container_name: fritzbox-metrics
    environment:
      - FRITZ_ADDRESS=192.168.99.1
      - FRITZ_USERNAME=user
      - FRITZ_PASSWORD=topsecret
      - FRITZ_USE_TLS=True
      - TELEGRAF_HOSTNAME=192.168.99.4
      - TELEGRAF_PORT=8094
      - SAMPLE_PERIOD=10
    restart: unless-stopped
```

The original version seems to have issues, but I guess my modifications should be OK:

here the original one:

```
version: "3.3"

networks:
  fritzbox-metrics:
    build: /opt/fritzbox-metrics/
    hostname: fritzbox-metrics
    container_name: fritzbox-metrics
    environment:
      - FRITZ_ADDRESS=192.168.178.1
      - FRITZ_USERNAME=metrics
      - FRITZ_PASSWORD=supersecret
      - FRITZ_USE_TLS=True
      - TELEGRAF_HOSTNAME=192.168.178.2
      - TELEGRAF_PORT=8094
      - SAMPLE_PERIOD=10
    restart: unless-stopped
```

The message I receive is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/karbu.jpg)

The -f I've added later on, makes no difference
As mentioned, the files are there

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why does it print out "enter image description here"?  Did you accidentally paste an image link instead of the text of the error message?  The obvious difference between the two YAML files is the second one incorrectly has `networks:` as the top-level block but the first has `services:` and that would definitely cause some errors.

Comment: You should remove the Dockerfile from the build path as that should be the directory only. But I think that if you would've run it as you wrote it here, it should have given you an errormessage about that like "unable to prepare context: context must be a directory". So I am not exactly sure what happened.